# How to re-pass passed data to another HTML page while using Flask?

Tags: python, forms, flask, bitcoin

I am able to have a user submit information through a form and have it passed to a 2nd HTML page, but I am having troubles allowing the user to submit information on that 2nd page with another form to submit and passing it to a 3rd HTML page.

Below is my code I am using. Basically I want to show a user the steps of the conversion process of bitcoin keys on multiple pages. Starting with inputting 256 binary digits on the first page, then converting that to decimal form on the 2nd page, then converting that to hexadecimal form on the 3rd page, etc.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/binary', methods=['POST','GET'])
def input_binary():
    if request.method == "POST":
        binary = request.form["binary"]
        return redirect(url_for("show_decimal", bin=binary))
    else:
        return render_template("binary.html")

@app.route('/<bin>', methods=['POST','GET'])
def show_decimal(bin):
    if request.method == "POST":
        decimal = request.form["decimal"]
        return redirect(url_for("show_hex", dec=decimal))
    else:
        decimal = int(bin, 2)
        return render_template("decimal.html", dec=decimal)

@app.route('/<dec>', methods=['POST','GET'])
def show_hex(dec):
    if request.method == "POST":
        hexadecimal = request.form["hexadecimal"]
        return redirect(url_for("show_pubkey", hex=hexadecimal))
    else:
        hexadecimal_string = hex(dec)
        return render_template("hex.html", h=hexadecimal_string)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am unable to pass information on a form from the 2nd page to the 3rd page. I keep getting an error that says "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2". It's like its trying to convert the decimal form to a decimal form again...

Comment: To pass a value from a `<form>` to the server, without showing it to the user, use `<input type="hidden">`

Answer (score 0):

**Hi**,Can you please try to run the code again after removing the base from from the int type conversion.

```py
   decimal = int(bin, 2)
```

You get the error because you are converting a non-string to an int with an explicit base.

Hope this was helpful.